# Python parsing to lower case and removing punctuation not functioning properly

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x

```
import string
remove = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, '\n ' + string.punctuation))

with open('data10.txt', 'r') as f:
for line in f:
    for word in line.split():
        w = f.read().translate(remove)
        print(word.lower())
```

I have this code here and for some reason, the `translate(remove)` is leaving a good amount of punctuation in the parsed file.

Comment: `w = f.read().translate(remove)` will read the entire file into a single string, call `translate(remove)` on that string and assign the result to `w`.  Is `w` ever used again?  If the code is complete here, then no, it's ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you reading the whole file within the for loop?

Try this:

```
import string
remove = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, '\n ' + string.punctuation))

with open('data10.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            word = word.translate(remove)
            print(word.lower())
```

This will print our the lower cased and stripped words, one per line. Not really sure if that's what you want.

Comment: That fixed it! This was my first time using python and i didn't notice that.